# Mongoose query with $near $or other field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to return documents by doing a query $or on different fields including a $near query with problems.

**Schema**

```
locationSchema{
    ...
    beacon: String,
    access_point: String,
    gps: [],
    ...
}

locationSchema.index({ gps: '2dsphere' });
```

**Query**

```
locations.find({
    '$or': [
        {
            gps: {
                '$near': {
                    '$geometry': {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [
                            13.1313131,
                            -4.444444
                        ]
                    },
                    '$maxDistance': 50,
                    distanceField: 'distance',
                    spherical: true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            access_point: '88:A6:BB:26:95:11'
        },
        {
            access_point: '88:A6:C6:26:CC:21'
        }
    ]
},
function(err,locations){
    //DosomethingwithfoundLocations
});
```

If I just do a query with only the `$near` input, there is one location returned as expected and if I do the query with just the list of `access_point`'s there is one location returned, but not when both queries are run at the same time.

I'm assuming this is a bug, but is there anyway I can get this type of query working?

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same problem, can we have any way to query using near and other elements together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported according to the docs. You can read more about it [HERE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

> $or supports geospatial clauses with the following exception for the near clause (near clause includes $nearSphere and $near). $or cannot contain a near clause with any other clause.

You can, however use [geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) and pass in the `center` operator to achieve the same goal. Keep in mind though that `geoWithin` does not sort the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have missed the statement within the docs. Doing two queries was simple as an alternative.